# Type of object to cast to when parsing DataGrid.SelectedItems (bound to a MySql DataTable)

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datatable

I have a simple `C# / WPF` application that reads a MySql database into a DataGrid.

```
<DataGrid  Height="470" Width="800" AutoGenerateColumns="True" CanUserResizeColumns="True" CanUserReorderColumns="True" x:Name="DgrReadWrite" ItemsSource="{Binding ''}"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" />
```

I load the Sql data into it like this:

```
string connStr = Service.getConnectionString();

string sql = "SELECT * FROM adat";
try
{
    MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
    MySqlCommand cmdSel = new MySqlCommand(sql, connection);

    MySqlDataAdapter da2 = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmdSel);
    da2.Fill(this.dt2);
    DgrReadWrite.DataContext = dt2;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("MySQL kapcsolódási hiba!", "Hiba!", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
}
```

When I press the delete button, this would happen:

```
for (int i = 0; i < this.dt2.Rows.Count; i++)
{

    // looping through DgrReadWrite.SelectedItems.Cast<SomethingReadable??>
    if (somethingReadable[0] == this.dt2.Rows[i][0].ToString())
    {
        dt2.Rows[i].Delete();
        DgrReadWrite.Items.Refresh();
    }
}
```

My question: what type should I cast the selected items so I can make sense of them in the method? Thank you in advance.

Comment: your question is to cast series of objects to something that is inside object?

Comment: Well, I just want to be able to retrieve the Index of the row selected, as in, the content of the first cell in the row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy to parse the data with DataRowView.

```
 foreach (DataRowView drRow in DgrReadWrite.SelectedItems)
            {
                listOfRowsToDelete.Add(drRow.Row);
                // put index numbers into a string for MySQL query
                ids = ids + drRow["index"] + ",";
            }
```